# Outdoor extension of hose spout

Tags: plumbing, water, outdoor, winterizing

My condo building used to have an extension of our hose spout (that's the best I can describe it, see pictures) that has been broken for some time. We're looking to re-build the whole thing, and since it would be nice if this version lasted a long time I'm seeking advice on the proper way to do this:

- It appears to have been made out of PVC pipe, but I think that's not meant for a pressure application like this? What would be a good alternative that wouldn't be too difficult to work with? Pex piping?
- Since this will have ~5 exit spouts, is it critically important that we have a large enough pipe diameter to maintain pressure?
- We live in Chicago, so how can we build the system to withstand the winter? I think we need a blowout hole?

I have done some of my own research but I'm still very naive, so any advice is much appreciated!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I see more of a freeze issue than anything. Heat tape and insulation may save you. Or pex

Answer (score 3):

PEX stands up pretty well to freezing. It's amazing what you can do to it and how it recovers. Freezing isn't a problem for PEX.  Still I would recommend draining it during the winter via a drain spigot at a low point in the plumbing. Depending upon the plumbing configuration, you may have to "blow it out" using compressed air.

Comment: Is PEX alright to use for a pressure application? Does something like this even count as pressure?

Comment: Yes, PEX is used all the time for plumbing. But to your questions...hmm, you have a spigot that is fed vertically for some distance, so yes, it is pressure.   All water systems work via pressure or the water wouldn't move!    And while I don't want to get snippy, this site (SE), expects contributors to try and solve their problem on their own first, do some basic research independently, then if you are stuck, feel free to ask here for help/answers.  Do some research on PEX and plumbing, you'll do yourself a big favor.

Comment: P.S.  The "pressure" may be created by gravity, IE: a water tower, or via a pressure tank, but for the water to move, it needs pressure.

Answer (score 1):

It froze ( containing water) and broke. There must be a drain valve at the low point to empty the line in cold weather.  That PVC is easily strong enough and large enough for 5 outlets. Nothing with stands ice expansion except possibly rubber. The challenge will be to make sure there are no isolated sections that contain water even with the low drain open.

Comment: I would differ.   I believe PEX stands up pretty well to freezing. Still I would recommend draining it during the winter via a drain spigot at a low point in the plumbing. Depending upon the plumbing configuration, you may have to "blow it out" using compressed air.

Comment: I agree and was thinking the same @george Anderson, make your comment an answer and I will upvote, I have seen pea freeze solid and when it thawed it was fine.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I just did that. +